# Book request on Generalized Method of Moments

Tags: self-study, references, generalized-moments, open-source

I found a very basic but usefull chapter on GMM available
[here](http://wps.aw.com/wps/media/objects/2387/2445250/Web_Extensions/4885_2fMURR_EX10W.pdf).

**Does anybody know the title and the author of the book containing this chapter?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book is called:

[Econometrics: A Modern Introduction, by Michael P. Murray](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Murray-Econometrics-A-Modern-Introduction/PGM294585.html?tab=contents)